# How to show date-time format like : 12 July at 12:43

Tags: php, datetime

Current I have showed : 9 December 20:02 with format code php: the_date('j F G:i');

But I want add string "at" like : 12 July **at** 12:43

Comment: What if you check documentation first?

Comment: do it twice + string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, Class is correct. That did not provide the correct output. You can, however do something like this:

```
$date = explode(' ', date('d F g:i'));
$new_date = $date[0] . ' ' . $date[1] . ' at ' .  $date[2];
echo $new_date;
```

Comment: that produces `10 December am31 4:49` probably needs to be `date('d F \a\t g:i');`